# Nested Doubly Linked Lists in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, nested-lists, doubly-linked-list

What is the best way to go about storing doubly linked lists inside of one doubly linked list? Preferably, I would like to use only one struct, like so:

```
struct node{
    string data;
    node* next = NULL;
    node* prev = NULL;
};
```

and use this to be able to store a doubly linked list inside of a doubly linked list to hold all of my doubly linked lists.

I have an ordinary insert function, but that wouldn't work because the parameters are `(node*& start, string data)`. So I've created another insertion method that attempts to store a doubly linked list into a node of a larger doubly linked list, but it gets cloudy from there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could argue that the best way is `std::list<std::list<std::string>>` for the general case.

Comment: Consider making your list a template if you're committed on using your own implementation.

Comment: Not much to go on here, but an interesting problem. `string data;` should be replaced by `LinkedList sublist;` or similar, but you'll likely need to work around the circular dependency this would result in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your node consists of data and links.

You could insert a linked list as part of the data section:

```
struct Node
{
  std::string Data
  std::list</*...*/> nested_list;
  Node * previous;
  Node * next;
};
```

If you don't like using `std::list` you could go with this:

```
struct Nested_Node
{
  Nested_Node * previous;
  Nested_Node * next;
  /* add data if necessary */
};

struct Node
{
  std::string data;
  Nested_Node * nested_head;
  Nested_Node * nested_tail;
  Node *        previous;
  Node *        next;
};
```

The above structures depend on how you want your nested linked list organized.

Each `Node` contains the head and tail of a linked list.  If you declare the nested list as a separate structure, you could replace the `Nested_Node` pointers with the list class.

Comment: How would you go about creating a list and then putting that list into the list of lists? I can't seem to figure out application of the objects.

Comment: Use `template` for the data type.  See my first example.  Use assignment operator. :-)  You may want to start using `std::list` instead of rolling your own.